# What caused seemingly irregular cases of Polish raising /o/ > /u/ (graphically ó)?

Tags: polish

According to Bethin’s *Polish Syllables* (a 1992 work I have seen cited but am unable to consult firsthand), the regular environment for raising of *o to /u/ (written as *ó*) in Polish is closed syllables before voiced non-nasal consonants. Certain irregular cases like *w ogóle* ‘in general’ might be explained as analogy from the nominative *ogół*. However, what explains cases like *dopóki* ‘until’ that are never involved in morphological alternations?

Comment: You'd have an easier time deciphering an ancient text written on stone. :)